# syntax error on php file add to cart

Tags: php

I'm getting various errors (syntax) on the following php file. The current php file is about onlineshops product-to-cart adding function. I get various errors. The errors start from the first `echo` and are listed as **`syntax error, unexpected 'echo'`**.

If I remove it, I get a **`syntax error, unexpected ';'`** on the next line.

Any help will be great. Thanks.

```
/* display cart */

if ( isset( $_SESSION['cart'] ) )
        (
        echo "<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width='500'>";
        $total = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $x)
        (
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from onlineshop WHERE id=$id",$db);
        $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);     
        $name = $myrow['name'];
        $name = substr($name,0,40);
        $price = $myrow['price'];
        $line_cost = $price *  $x;
        $total = $total + $line_cost;

         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td allign='left'> $name </td>";
         echo "<td align = 'right'>X $x <a href='cart.php?id=".$id."&action=remove'> reduce </a></td>";
         echo "<td align = 'right'>= $line_cost £";
         echo "</tr>";
        )
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align ='right'><br>Total=</td>";
        echo "<td align ='right'><b><br> $total £</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    )
    else
        echo "Cart is empty";
```

Comment: `if` and `else` use curly braces `{` `}` for their bodies not parenthesis `(` `)` same in `for`

Comment: Same error from two users in 30 minutes of each other

Comment: A definite déjà vue. Where have I seen this earlier? @JohnConde ;-)

Comment: Kinda weird. Haven't seen this error in a while then two practically on top of each other. Must be that kind of day.

Comment: Maybe Easter Monday has that affect (*on some*). An Easter favorite probably. The rounded parts in the brackets makes them think of Easter Eggs.

Comment: I manage to fix everything but I get this error on line -- $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from onlineshop WHERE id=$id",$con); -- the error message is * mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong braces. Replace `()` with `{}` in `if` statement and `foreach` loop :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    echo "<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width='500'>";
    $total = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $x){
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from onlineshop WHERE id=$id",$db);
        $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);     
        $name = $myrow['name'];
        $name = substr($name,0,40);
        $price = $myrow['price'];
        $line_cost = $price *  $x;
        $total = $total + $line_cost;

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td allign='left'> $name </td>";
        echo "<td align = 'right'>X $x <a href='cart.php?id=".$id."&action=remove'> reduce </a></td>";
        echo "<td align = 'right'>= $line_cost £";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align ='right'><br>Total=</td>";
    echo "<td align ='right'><b><br> $total £</b></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}else
    echo "Cart is empty";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{}` braces instead of `()` for `if`'s or loop's content block.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
//....
}
```

instead of

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) (
//....
)
```

And the same to `foreach` loop.

Comment: dont forget the `foreach`

Comment: You used curly brackets in each example

Comment: after that I get an error on line -- $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from onlineshop WHERE id=$id",$db); -- error msg *syntax error, unexpected ';' *

Comment: *"You should use"* --- Which should be rephrased to "you MUST..." ;-)

Comment: Thanks Logan, you're right of course. @cmario - as Logan said, the same for `foreach`.

Comment: @cmario did you forget about the foreach? :P